# Break out of IF statement if condition satisfied

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

How would I end an if statement upon being satisfied but then execute the else if otherwise in a  stored procedure?

I have tried putting an end if after the if statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `db`.`tbl` WHERE email = "email@domain.com") END IF;
ELSE INSERT INTO `db`.`tbl` (email) VALUES ("email@domain.com"); END IF;
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an ignore insert?

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO  `db`.`tbl` SET `email`= 'email@domain.com';
```

You would have to create a unique index on email.

Check [here](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html) for some reference.

Comment: Do you not have to be using a primary key with `insert ignore` tho?

Comment: This is a mysql only feature. But most databases have something similar.

Comment: I guess to set multiple fields its just `AND`

Answer (score 0):

If this is for inserting if the row does not already exists, you shoul use this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (value1, value2) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM `table` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `table` 
    WHERE value1='stuff for value1' AND value2='stuff for value2'
);
```